# Plugging in a point not on a plane, into the plane's equation

Tags: analytic-geometry

Say a plane *P* has a given equation ax+by+cz=d.  Given a point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ that is not included in *P*.  When $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is plugged into $f(x,y,z)=ax+by+cz-d$ and it outputs some nonzero $e$.

What does $e$ represent?

What information does this give us about $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ in relation to *P*?

I believe that the set of all points such that $f(x,y,z)=e$ form a plane with equation $ax+by+cz=d+e$. Is this all that's useful about the extra information? The corresponding parallel plane that the point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ belongs to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that $ax+by+cd=d+e$ describes another plane. 
More precisely a plane *parallel* to the first one.

The value of $e$ is related to the distance between these two planes (or between the point and the plane in the first part of the question).
More precisely, this distance equals $\frac{|e|}{\sqrt{ a^2+b^2+c^2}}$.
The sign of $e$ determines the side of the given plane.
With this point of view, the points in the given plane are simply those points having distance $0$ from the plane :)